# Is sum of every row and column in matrix same

Tags: c

I have a problem. I need to write a program that checks if every row has the same sum, and if every column has same sum.

Example:

```
 3 3 3 
 3 3 3
```

In this example output should be "YES" for rows and "YES" for columns.

Another example:

```
 4 5 6
 6 4 5
```

In this example, output should be "YES" for rows because sum of 1st and 2nd row is the same (15), and it should be "NO" for columns because sum is not the same (10,9,11).

I have made code that checks first row and first column than it compares if they are same as the other ones. I have made it to check if its not but I don't know how to check it if it is, I mean how to output "YES" for both cases.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int mat[100][100];
  int n, m;
  int i, j;
  int sumak = 0;
  int sumar = 0;
  int sumarp = 0;
  int sumakp = 0;
  do {
    printf("Unesite brojeve M i N: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
  } while (m < 0 || m > 100 || n < 0 || n > 100);

  printf("Unesite clanove matricee: ");
  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
    }
  }
  // suma of first row
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      sumarp = sumarp + mat[i][j];
    }
    sumarp = sumarp + mat[i][j];
  }
  // sum of all rows
  for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      sumar = sumar + mat[i][j];
    }
    if (sumarp != sumar) {
      printf("NE");
    } else {
      sumar = 0;
      continue;
    }
  }

  // sum of the first column

  for (j = 0; j<1; j++) {
    for (i = 0;  i< m;i++ ) {
      sumakp = sumakp + mat[i][j];
    }
    sumakp = sumakp + mat[i][j];
  }

  // sum of every column

  for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
    for (i= 0; i < m; i++) {
      sumak = sumak + mat[i][j];
    }
    if (sumakp == sumak) {
        sumak=0;
      continue;
    } 
    if(sumakp!=sumak)
    {
        printf("NE");
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        printf("DA");
    } 
  }
}
```

So if someone can explain me how to do the rest of it.

Thank you!

Comment: Note: this is a great place to implement short-circuiting. If you have three columns, and columns 1 and 2 do not have the same sum, then you can immediately return false without evaluating column 3.

Comment: @chris yes i know. Im doing that, its ok for "NO" but i dont know how to print yes if they are the same. :|

Comment: Print NO (or NE) in an `else` clause after the `if` where you print YES (or DA).  It might be that you have to record whether you've printed NO and only print YES if you've not printed NO at the end of a loop.

Comment: There's no need for the outer `for` loop when you're just summing the first row or column. Just use the inner loop and hard-code the row or column number as `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable to indicate whether any of the rows or columns didn't match. Then check it at the end of the loop.

Here's how to do it for rows. Columns are similar, just switch the order of the `i` and `j` loops.

```
int all_matched = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    int sumar = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        sumar += mat[i][j];
    }
    if (sumar != sumarp) {
        all_matched = 0;
        break;
    }
}
if (all_matched) {
    printf("EQ\n");
} else {
    printf("NE\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was really helpfull.